# Possible Mistaken Empty Statement - Do Nothing in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following

```
    WindowState WindowState_ = WindowState.Normal;
    ...
    public override void Load()
    {
       ...
        var Value = StringLoad("WindowState", "");
        if (Enum.TryParse(Value, out WindowState_))
            ;
        else
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
       ...
    }
```

I could rewrite as

```
        var Value = StringLoad("WindowState", "");
        if (! Enum.TryParse(Value, out WindowState_))           
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
```

I find ! a bit ugly and often hard to spot, and there is no ifNot or ifFail in C# HaHa!
is there a "Do Nothing" like the semicolon in C# above, which will NOT generate the warning and without turning this warning globally off.

I am open to other suggestions leading better more readable coding

Thank you.

Comment: `Enum.TryParse(...) == false` is also another suggestion

Comment: You should ask yourself if it really makes sense for a programmer to instruct a computer to do nothing when it's default state is to do nothing unless you tell it to do something (by programming it).

Comment: btw we do have do nothing instruction in assembly, in 8086 the instruction is `NOP` ;) @Juan

Comment: Yes @M.kazemAkhgary but that has a much different (lower level) purpose.

Comment: there is no do nothing, but empty block: `if(check) { }; else`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you use use a local variable. Whilst this does not remove the need for the `!` operator, it's not hidden by a complicated expression:

```
var Value = StringLoad("WindowState", "");
var isValidWindowState = Enum.TryParse(Value, out WindowState_);
if (!isValidWindowState)
{
    WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
}
```

On top of that it outlines what the `Enum.TryParse` is for in this context. [Extract Variable](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-variable) is also a well-known [refactoring](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring).

As M.kazem Akhgary pointed out, the runtime behaviour of your application is not changed, because it's (most probably) compiled to the same bytecode.

Comment: its also worth mentioning that all of these are compiled to same thing. so that doesn't mean using local variable is better or not (in terms of using  resourses)

Comment: I like this for readability even though there goes that bang sign again (NOT operator), I hate it when I have to think in negation :).  I do tend to use intermediate variables it just did not click here :),  I will probably have to accept this.

Answer (score 2):

I generally do this:

```
    var Value = StringLoad("WindowState", "");
    if (Enum.TryParse(Value, out WindowState_))
    {
         //do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
    }
```

Comment: I personally feel "//do nothing" statements have no place in coding. After all, the computer already "does nothing" unless you instruct it to do something. It works anyways and the compiler is probably smart enough to flip it for you, but I still don't like the line of thinking.

Comment: @juan it's not that I want to tell the computer do nothing, it's just often I tend to want to deal with the positive outcome first, just how my brain is wired.  I often find APIs phrased the other I want to express a certain logic, for example there is provision for isClosed() but no isOpen(), so I am "forced" to write if ( ! isClosed() ) ....   I have no issue with Edward's suggestion, though I see the up-voting going with Mattias's answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the inline conditional syntax:

```
WindowState = (Enum.TryParse(Value, out WindowState_)) ? WindowState 
                                                       : System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the check, because the out variable is set to it's default value when parsing fails:

> [If the parse operation fails, result contains the default value of the underlying type of TEnum.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499)

```
var WindowState_ = WindowState.Maximized;

Enum.TryParse("some incorrect value", out WindowState_);

Debug.Print(WindowState_.ToString()); // "Normal"
```

Comment: I am not aware that there is a "default of the underlying type"  for example the doc for WindowState does not mention a default?  Can you elaborate?  What I want to code a different outcome?  Thank you.
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.WindowState);k(WindowState);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework

Comment: @Marie I think I misunderstood your intention as my example doesn't follow the logic in your sample (doesn't set the `WindowState` to Normal if parse fails). The [`default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25tdedf5) for numeric value types is 0 and [`WindowState.Normal` is 0](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,27ce608a1c9bb620), so `default(System.Windows.WindowState) == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal`

Answer (score 0):

When there is no else anticipated, I tend to want to write Mattias code like this:

```
var Value = StringLoad("WindowState", "");
var WindowStateIsNotValid = ! Enum.TryParse(Value, out WindowState_);
if (WindowStateIsNotValid)
    WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
```

other names like WindowStateFailedToLoad... comes to mind..